# Xen DomU Remote Management utility

Tags: windows, gratis, debian

I require a free (as in beer) program or service for accessing and controlling a Xen Hypervisor running on Debian Jessie.

- Support Xen DomU (the Free Open Source Software hypervisor, NOT the full-blown XenServer)
- Work in the Local Area Network
- Free (as in beer)
- GUI interface

It can be web-based, or run on my Windows workstation completely. I already have access to the `xl` tools via PuTTY, but I'd like a graphical representation of what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Cockpit can do what I want:

- Supports Xen, Virtualbox and even KVM
- Works in the LAN by default, but can be opened up to other users/networks
- Free
- Runs as a GUI in a web browser.